# How to group the outcomes of a query by the values in another column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, case, aggregate-functions

I have a table called `vegetation` with 2 columns:
`type`, `count`

I want to sum the count for all the rows where count value is smaller than the average count and all those for which it is higher.

I don't know how to reflect this in the group by clause... (or somewhere else?).

I guess that another way of doing it should be by assigning a value to all less-than-average data and another value to all higher-than-average data and then group by this value. But I just started and can not figure out how to do that either.

Comment: Please include PostgreSQL version, table definitions (including data types), sample data and expected results in all questions. It's possible to answer without as Erwin has shown, but it's certainly easier if you include that information.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT sum(CASE WHEN ct <= x.avg_ct THEN ct ELSE 0 END) AS sum_ct_low
      ,sum(CASE WHEN ct >  x.avg_ct THEN ct ELSE 0 END) AS sum_ct_hi
FROM vegetation v
    ,(SELECT avg(ct) AS avg_ct FROM vegetation) x
```

The average is a single value, you can just `CROSS JOIN` the subquery to the base table (comma separated list of tables means cross-joining).
Then filter with a simple `CASE` statement.

I use `ct` instead of `count`, since that's a [reserved word in SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html).

Comment: Yes sorry for using the count, i was trying to simplify my problem. Thanks for your help, I found out how to use case now!

Comment: @user1832041: No problem. I just keep mentioning it, so the general public gets the idea.